# Modifying dynamic HTML table after it's been generated

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to JS and HTML in general, so bear with me on this one.. I have a function loadData() that is called when the page load that dynamically creates an HTML table. I want to modify a few aspects of the table once it's been created (contents of the updateTable function). I tried including these modifications at then end of the loadData method, but nothing happens. However, if I move the updates out to a separate function and call this with a button click, the updates work. Even if I call updateTable at the end of loadData, it still doesn't work. I even tried appending the onLoad attribute to the table so that it would call updateTable().

I have a feeling that the reason for this behavior is because the table is not actually loaded when the updates are firing inside the loadData function itself, so the JS is trying to modify elements that don't even exist yet. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out why this would be the case if the updateTable function is being called *at the end* of the loadData function...

```
function updateTable() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    maxCols = 0;
    for ( var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
      var cols = rows[i].cells.length; 
      if ( cols > maxCols ){
        maxCols = cols;
      }
    }
    headerCols = rows[0].cells.length; 
    diff = maxCols - headerCols + 1; 
    tbl.rows[0].cells[3].colSpan = diff;
    tbl.rows[0].cells[3].align = "center";

    for ( var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
      var cols = rows[i].cells.length;
      for (var a=cols; a < maxCols; a++){
        rows[i].insertCell(a);
      }
    }
    //console.log(maxCols); 
}

function loadData() {

    d3.text("data.csv", function(data) {
        var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);
        var container = d3.select('#contTable');
           .append("table").attr('class','table').attr('id','dataTable')

        .selectAll("tr")
            .data(parsedCSV).enter()
            .append("tr")

        .selectAll("td")
            .data(function(d) {
                return d;
            }).enter()
            .append("td")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d;
            });
    });
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Need the HTML to see exactly where each function is declared, defined, called, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the code you posted, `updateTable` isn't called *at all*. This answer assumes your observed behavior happens when you call `updateTable` at the very end of `loadData`, outside the `d3.text` callback.

Move the call to `updateTable` to the end of the `d3.text` callback, so it gets run immediately after `#dataTable` has been set up.

Your suspicion is correct. `d3.text` loads `data.csv` asynchronously, so the code that creates `#dataTable` doesn't get run until after the browser's retrieved `data.csv`. Meanwhile, the rest of `loadData` keeps right on going. It hits `updateTable`, but since the engine hasn't had the chance to run the `d3.text` callback yet, there's no `#dataTable` to operate on.

[For more on Javascript's asynchronicity, see this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667087/9029328)

Comment: Thanks, AuxTaco! I moved updateTable to inside the d3.text callback and it worked! This concept of sync/async processing is a bit foreign to me as all the bash/python scripting I'm familiar with is executed synchronously unless specified otherwise..  I'll have to do some reading on asynchronicity. Thanks again!